# In grails, how to change the language to arabic

Tags: grails, internationalization

I am creating application using grails. I have to use two languages english and arabic. By default english, then when arabic needed it will change. What i have to do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly with [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/i18n.html), you need to use params `lang=langCOde` like `/book/list?lang=es` (`es` for spain, `ar` - for arabic).

Grails will automatically switch the user's locale and store it in a cookie so subsequent requests will have the new header.

Comment: I have done this but the arabic characters are shown as ???????. I don't know why ?

Comment: @sikander, it can be a problem with encoding of your messages_ar.properties file.